# Is it possible to query specific Wordpress Attachment files (.ppt & .pdf) and output them in a list?

Tags: attachments

The files are `.ppt` and `.pdf` files (not images).

Will it be possible to query these types of attachments and output it in a unordered list?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it's documented in Codex but quick search in code shows that you can query by mime type. For jpeg images that would be something like:

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'post_status' => 'any',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg',

             ) );
```

Not sure what types WP uses for files you need, don't have such in test stack to check.

Comment: do you think this can be done with multiple mime-types? PDF & PPT? OR can you just exclude a mime-type?

Comment: @daniel Crabbe according to quick look at code it should take array or comma-separated list of multiple mime types just fine.